# Creating a scrollbar for a s:Panel in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, scrollbar

I am new to flex development.

In my proj, I have created a panel using this

```
<s:Panel x="46" y="193" width="75%" height="75%" dropShadowVisible="false">
```

what happens here is that, the part of the panel goes out of the browser view and I need to include scrollbars so that I can scroll to the right end and bottom end of the panel itself.

I would like to know how I can add scrollbars to the s:panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap it with a scroller!  ;)

```
<s:Scroller>
...your content to scroll...
</s:Scroller>
```

Comment: I actually need to add scrollbar to the main window itself and not just to the panel. because for me what happens is that, the panel frame itself gets cut on the right and bottom and I am unable to figure how to add scrollbar to the main window itself.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use your own scrollbars you need three things:
1. Your main (parent) container should implement IViewport (any subclasses of s:Group would do)
2. Set container's property 'clipAndEnableScrolling' to 'true'.
3. You assign this main container as 'viewport' property of your scrollbar.

HTH,
FTQuest